# ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000 , how to split the string

Tags: c, string, oracle, split, ora-01795

How to split the following string?

```
      A.x IN (changeList),
```

changeList has the following value, so that it makes the clause like this:

```
       A.x IN (HEXTORAW('1E2956B9266F11DDA85810000000C959'),HEXTORAW   
             ('ADD834AD6A3911DF923C10000000C959'),HEX...........
```

The above IN has more than 1000 values and hence ORA-01795 error, how to modify it so that i have

A.X IN (id1, ..id999) OR A.x IN (id1000,...), Any c code would help me...

Comment: I would consider putting the values in an external table, or passing them as an array rather than trying to force them into an `in` clause - [here's an example using numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18675238/266304), which can fairly easily be adapted for strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must write a loop that executes the SQL in chunks with 1000 entries each.

Alternatively you can insert the values into a table and then do a subselect with the `IN` clause, because with a subselect, the limitation of 1000 entries doesn't apply. This limit is only when you use an SQL with an hardcoded value string.

Something like this:

```
select *
from mytable t
where t.column1 = value
and t.column2 in
(
    select my_values
    from my_temp_table
)
```