# Oracle in C#, bind variables, and queries like ID IN (1, 2, 3)

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, odac, bind-variables

I'm looking for a C# ODAC adaptation of the following Java technique, where code is able to bind an array of numbers (the array size can vary) into a non-PL/SQL `SELECT` statement and then use the resulting array in a `WHERE ID IN (...)` style check.

http://rafudb.blogspot.com/2011/10/variable-inlist.html

Here's another example of this technique used in OCI-based C programs:

[Oracle OCI, bind variables, and queries like ID IN (1, 2, 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18603281/oracle-oci-bind-variables-and-queries-like-id-in-1-2-3)

Specifically, we want to execute a query like

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(:1))
```

And pass in an array of Numbers into `:1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code:

```
oraParam.UdtTypeName = "SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST";
VArray newArray = new VArray();
newArray.Array = new Int32[] {12,24,42};
oraParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
oraParam.Value = newArray;

string query = @"Select * from TABLE(:1) ";
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(query, MyConnection);
command.Parameters.Add(oraParam);
OracleDataReader reader;
var m_connection = new OracleConnection("The CONNECTION STRING");
m_connection.Open();
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
reader.Close();
m_connection.Close();
```

Which is followed by the following Helper Classes:

```
class VArray : IOracleCustomType, INullable
{
    [OracleArrayMapping()]
    public Int32[] Array;

    private OracleUdtStatus[] m_statusArray;
    public OracleUdtStatus[] StatusArray
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_statusArray;
        }
        set
        {
            this.m_statusArray = value;
        }
    }

    private bool m_bIsNull;

    public bool IsNull
    {
        get
        {
            return m_bIsNull;
        }
    }

    public static VArray Null
    {
        get
        {
            VArray obj = new VArray();
            obj.m_bIsNull = true;
            return obj;
        }
    }

    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
    {
        object objectStatusArray = null;
        Array = (Int32[])OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, 0, out objectStatusArray);
        m_statusArray = (OracleUdtStatus[])objectStatusArray;
    }

    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
    {
        OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, 0, Array, m_statusArray);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (m_bIsNull)
            return "VArray.Null";
        else
        {
            string rtnstr = String.Empty;
            if (m_statusArray[0] == OracleUdtStatus.Null)
                rtnstr = "NULL";
            else
                rtnstr = Array.GetValue(0).ToString();
            for (int i = 1; i < m_statusArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (m_statusArray[i] == OracleUdtStatus.Null)
                    rtnstr += "," + "NULL";
                else
                    rtnstr += "," + Array.GetValue(i).ToString();
            }
            return "VArray(" + rtnstr + ")";
        }
    }
}

[OracleCustomTypeMapping("SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST")]
public class VArrayFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory, IOracleArrayTypeFactory
{
    // IOracleCustomTypeFactory
    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new VArray();
    }

    // IOracleArrayTypeFactory Interface
    public Array CreateArray(int numElems)
    {
        return new Int32[numElems];
    }

    public Array CreateStatusArray(int numElems)
    {
        // CreateStatusArray may return null if null status information 
        // is not required.
        return new OracleUdtStatus[numElems];
    }
}
```

### DESCRIPTION:

The general idea is that similar to the OCI example, you have to cast the parameter as a SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST (Or other valid type).  That type is not defined by default in the C# OracleDBType so you have to use the UdtTypeName and a custom Factory/Class to bind successfully.

This was inspired from the [following post on defining custom types](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33829/How-to-use-Oracle-11g-ODP-NET-UDT-in-an-Oracle-Sto).

### Limits:

This exact solution will only work with INT/NUMBER values because it is piggybacking off of the SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST table type. If it is needed for other types you may need to find/write additional custom table types.

Comment: This dropped straight into our codebase with almost no work on my part! Good find.