# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

Tags: java, sql, oracle, named-query

I have a method in Dao Class that returns `List<Object[]>` back and I am using named Query

```
public List<Object[]> getListByCustomer(Session session, int customerId, List<Integer> strIds) {
  Query namedQuery = session.createSQLQuery(QueryConstants.EXPORT);
  namedQuery.setParameter("customer", customerId);
  namedQuery.setParameter("stringId", strIds);
  List<Object[]> objects = namedQuery.list();
  return objects;
}
```

I want to pass `List<Integer> strIds` in stringId into the named query as follows :

```
public class QueryConstants {
  public static final String EXPORT = 
    "SELECT sv.NAME, sv.TYPE, sv.CLIENT_ADDRESS, sv.NAME_REDUNDANT, sv.DEPARTURE_DATE, s1.CODE,sv.STATE, sv.CODE "
    + "FROM VIEW sv, PROCESS p1, SET s1 " 
    + "WHERE sv.R_ID = p1.R_ID and p1.ISSUER_ID = s1.USER_ID and sv.CUSTOMER_ID = :customer and sv.R_ID IN (:stringId)";
}
```

But I get `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY.`

Also when I remove `sv.R_ID IN (:stringId)` from the query it works fine and
when I pass `Integer(strIds)` instead of `List<Integer> strIds` into the query it works fine.

I'm using Oracle 10g.

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378824/adding-in-clause-list-to-a-jpa-query

Comment: yes tried with removing (...) i.e sv.R_ID IN :stringId still same error.

Comment: What is your JPA vendor? Also can you try namedQuery.setParameter("stringId", Arrays.toString(strIds.toArray())); with or without the (...) ?

Comment: You can't bind a List for use in an `IN` clause. You'll need to convert it to an Oracle array object, treat that as a table, and use a join.

Comment: Does anybody know if parameter binding for IN clauses is supported in SQL queries (as opposed to JPQL or HQL)? Most likely not.

Comment: @Codo - in plain SQL, no, each value in the `IN` clause has to be bound individually. [Or you can use an array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21034016/266304); as a join, or I guess as a subquery within the `IN`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you just need to use

```
 IN :stringId
```

instead of

```
 IN (:stringId)
```

For JPA

```
namedQuery.setParameter("stringId", strIds);
```

is correct, but for Hibernate you should use

```
namedQuery.setParameterList("stringId", strIds);
```

Comment: need To use namedQuery.setParameterList("stringId", strIds); Thanks

Answer (score 31):

This is a very misleading error, and may root from different causes, for me I was setting a parameter that it was supposedly a number but at runtime it was setting `null`, hence it was `binary`. On a separate occasion got this error due to bean creation error in spring and was not setting the parameter correctly as well.

Answer (score 5):

Case your param is list. If list is empty then raise error, you must check that list not empty to avoid error.
Case your param is single value. Let use TO_NUMBER(:your_param) to avoid error.
It working on me.

Comment: Thank you for this, TO_NUMBER() worked on the param. No matter what I did JPA was turning null into a varbinary type and TO_NUMBER() in the query fixed it.

Comment: TO_NUMBER() gave invalid sql statement error

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this same exception and found the below reason for that -

In my entity, a field was mapped to a custom object (Parent child relationship - @ManyToOne). Later, the relationship annotation was removed by developer but the datatype was not changed.

After removing the @ManyToOne annotation, the @Column annotation should have been used with appropriate data type (Integer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using HQL (in the repository of spring data) with an Entity mapped with @Enumerated (ORDINAL). I was trying to use the the enum object directly in the where clausule. The solution was to use TO_NUMBER(:your_param) as mentioned by the member above.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but for a different reason. In my case it was due to the order the parameters were supplied being different from the order defined in the query. I assumed (wrongly) that because the parameters were named the order didn't matter. Sadly, it seems like it does.