# Spring Data JPA - problem with null parameter for NUMBER column type

Tags: java, spring, orm, spring-data-jpa

I want to make dynamic query in which if particular parameter is sent, the Native query should filter the result based on it. In case it's null, it should not reflect the result.

I am using Spring Data JPA with Native query mechanism + Oracle DB

For String parameters this approach works fine

```
:email is null or s.email = :email
```

but for Integer parameters when they have value, the Query works but if the parameter is null the query fails with the error

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

I am using the exactly the same approach for for Integer instead of String

I am wondering whether the problem is on my side or it's some kind of bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23218102/java-sql-sqlexception-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-number-got-bi)

Comment: Thank you for the response. No, it's different kind of problem producing the same error. In my case I expect the parameter to be as a "null" value. This topic is some kind of related with my problem but the proposed solutions work only for String parameter, not for Integer  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780226/spring-data-ignore-parameter-if-it-has-a-null-value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Oracle DB it's not worked this way. A workaround is using JPQL like

```
SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE :id is null OR s.id = COALESCE(:id, -1)
```

Or for native query use `TO_NUMBER` function of oracle

```
SELECT s FROM Entity s WHERE :id is null OR s.id = TO_NUMBER(:id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Eklavya. Your solution works as expected. Can you explain please why when the parameter has value, for example Integer age = 1; the query work but when the value is null, for example Integer age = null; it fails?

Comment: @Tsvetoslav Here you find details for that https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4291/why-does-null-not-work-in-oracle